# Why is my for loop not working on object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My for loop is not going through any properties of my object. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
public var previousPresets:HTMLExportOptions;

public function savePresets():void {
        if (previousPresets==null) {
            previousPresets = new HTMLExportOptions();
        }

        // set properties
        for (var property:String in previousPresets) {
            if (property in this) {
                previousPresets[property] = this[property];
            }
        }
    }
```

And the class:

```
public class HTMLExportOptions extends ExportOptions {

    public function HTMLExportOptions() {

    }

    public var addZoom:Boolean;
    public var showScreenshotBackground:Boolean;
    public var showFullHTMLPageSource:Boolean;
    public var useInlineStyles:Boolean;
    public var showBorders:Boolean;
    public var showBordersCSS:String;
}
```

More Related Questions:

Do you always have to set property enumerable for it to work? Would making my class explicitly extend Object cause any changes? How about marking it dynamic?

Comment: `for in` I believe in AS3 only works with dynamic properties

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I remember reading something about this a long time ago but I've used for in before and don't remember encountering this issue. I'm experiencing a for loop not working either. I updated the question.

Comment: explicitly extending object won't change anything

Comment: see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153331/how-to-make-an-user-defined-object-iterable-in-as3

Comment: You can also get all the vars of a class by parsing the xml results of: `flash.utils.describeType`

Comment: Why does `this` have a duplicated list of options?  How are those properties of `this` created and set? Please show all the code related to those properties.

Comment: You could also use [`Proxy`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#nextName%28%29) to make the properties enumerable. However, there's probably a better solution. Since you already have a nice class to define all the options, why not simply refer to its properties directly instead of copying them onto `this`?

Comment: @null the savePresets function is in another class

Comment: @Aaron I might but there are more options listed here. Also inherited properties. My actual comment is "lazy attempt to set properties" at the same time it might ensure I don't forget properties if I add more.

Comment: Still, I don't see why your `this` object couldn't simply have a single property of type `HTMLExportOptions`.

Comment: @Aaron it could. It might try that but I've always had options on the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using describeType sort of works but it still needed some work and organization. This method gets an XML List of the properties and where they were declared.

```
var properties:Array = getPropertiesArray(options);


public static function getPropertiesArray(object:Object, sort:Boolean = true):Array {
    var describedTypeRecord:DescribeTypeCacheRecord = mx.utils.DescribeTypeCache.describeType(object);
    var typeDescription:* = describedTypeRecord.typeDescription;
    var hasFactory:Boolean = typeDescription.factory.length()>0;
    var factory:XMLList = typeDescription.factory;
    var itemsLength:int;
    var itemsList:XMLList;
    var propertyName:String;
    var properties:Array = [];

    itemsList = hasFactory ? factory.variable + factory.accessor : typeDescription.variable + typeDescription.accessor;
    itemsLength = itemsList.length();

    for (var i:int;i<itemsLength;i++) {
        var item:XML = XML(itemsList[i]);
        propertyName = item.@name;
        properties.push(propertyName);
    }

    if (sort) properties.sort();

    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation of the for..in statement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) states the following:

> Iterates over the **dynamic** properties of an object or elements in an array and executes statement for each property or element. Object properties are not kept in any particular order, so properties may appear in a seemingly random order. Fixed properties, such as **variables and methods defined in a class, are not enumerated by the for..in statement**. To get a list of fixed properties, use the describeType() function, which is in the flash.utils package.

The real question is why you have the properties on both `this` and `previousPresets`.

Instead of creating the `previousPresets` object only when calling that method `savePresets()`, have it from the beginning and always save the values into that object instead of `this`. Why bloat `this` with all those values?

Comment: Hmm. Good point. I was thinking of the XML class when I wrote this. It has that save settings method and also lets you set static vars.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts you can add static variables to every class.